# I mistakenly closed a direct message window on Slack, and I don't know with whom it was. How can I re-open it?

Tags: slack

I mistakenly closed a direct message window on Slack, and I don't know with whom the direct message window was. How can I re-open it?

I clicked here:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Click on "Direct Messages" to bring up a list of recent conversations:

[image]

Comment: This does not work anymore (using version 4.13.x).

Answer (score 10):

Easiest solution is to search for `To:@yourname`
Then all the recent messages to you are displayed in time order.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Slack as a web application, e.g. via the Mac/Windows apps or in your browser, you can reopen the most-recently-closed Direct Message window by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. You can also use this shortcut to navigate to the last channel you were in.

Do be aware that since this is the "go back one step in history" web browser shortcut, pressing this key combination too many times can cause Slack to reload itself from the sign-in page.

Comment: its not win+[ it's ctrl+[

Comment: Thanks, edited and fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Click the plus icon next to Direct Messages in the left sidebar.
Search for the person you'd like to message.
Click Go to start your new DM conversation.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, this will revert to the last state.